# count number of matching fields in each line

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I have a file where each line has a certain number of fields matching "./." that looks something like:

```
chrM    57  .   T   C   4848.99 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./. 1/1:1,149:150:99:4903,439,0 0/0:202,0:202:99:0,541,6030 0/0:249,1:250:99:0,646,7558 0/0:249,1:250:99:0,647,7484 0/0:111,0:111:99:0,304,3346 0/0:171,0:172:99:0,397,4599 0/0:118,0:118:99:0,340,3827 0/0:247,0:247:99:0,650,7312 0/0:218,0:219:99:0,611,6728 0/0:242,0:242:99:0,686,7589 0/0:250,0:250:99:0,689,7599 0/0:144,0:144:99:0,409,4608 0/0:250,0:250:99:0,680,7585 0/0:141,3:144:99:0,321,4233 0/0:71,0:71:99:0,205,2260   0/0:204,0:205:99:0,568,6312 ./. 0/0:191,0:191:99:0,523,5874 0/0:249,0:250:99:0,665,7443 0/0:142,0:143:99:0,340,3991 0/0:218,0:218:99:0,575,6612 0/0:247,0:247:99:0,665,7412 0/0:250,0:250:99:0,692,7768 0/0:250,0:250:99:0,689,7749 0/0:247,2:249:99:0,674,7574
```

I would like to count the number of fields exactly matching "./." in each line, and print the number of matches for each line. I believe I could do something like the code below but code doesn't work (I am new to perl). I think there should be an easier solution in awk.

```
#! perl -w  

my$F=shift@ARGV;
open IN, "$F";
while(<IN>){
    $num1++ while ($string1 =~ m/\.\/\./g);
    print "The first line has $num1\n";
    next;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print "Line $. has ", ( split m|\./\.| ) - 1, "\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl dataFile [>outFile]`

The brackets indicate an optional parameter you can use to send output to a file.

The script `split`s each line on the field-pattern that you want to match, then returns the number of elements-1 from that `split` as the number of fields matching "./.".  On your sample line, it returns:

`Line 1 has 2`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
perl -nE '$count = () = m{\./\.}g; say "Line $. has $count";' file
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/j4Z6Gk)

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) c+=($i=="./."); printf "Line %s has %s\n",NR,c+0;}' file
Line 1 has 2
```

#### How it works

By default, awk splits each record (line) into fields.  We loop through all the fields looking for equality with `./.`.

- `c=0`

  Set the count to zero.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) c+=($i=="./.")`

  Increment count `c` by one every time a field exactly matches `./.`.

  `$i` is the content of the i'th field.  `$i=="./."` is one if the field exactly matches `./.`.  Thus, `c+=($i=="./.")` increments `c` by one for each matching field.
- `printf "Line %s has %s\n",NR,c+0`

  Print the results for this line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an iterator to capture each line. The match count syntax in Perl is a little strange too

```
my$F=shift@ARGV;
open IN, "$F";
$s = "\.\/\.";
while($string1 = <IN>){
    $num1 = () = $string1 =~ m/$s/gi;
    print "foo: $num1 $string1\n";
    next;
```